# What's the intuition behind contrastive learning or approach?

Tags: neural-networks, unsupervised-learning, intuition, semi-supervised-learning, transfer-learning

Maybe a noobs query, but recently I have seen a surge of papers w.r.t contrastive learning (a subset of semi-supervised learning).

Some of the prominent and recent research papers which I read, which detailed this approach are:

- Representation Learning with Contrastive Predictive Coding
  @ https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03748
- SimCLR-v1: A Simple Framework for Contrastive Learning of Visual Representations @ https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.05709
- SimCLR-v2: Big Self-Supervised Models are Strong Semi-Supervised Learners @ https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.10029
- MoCo-v1: Momentum Contrast for Unsupervised Visual Representation Learning @ https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.05722
- MoCo-v2: Improved Baselines with Momentum Contrastive Learning @ https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.04297
- PIRL: Self-Supervised Learning of Pretext-Invariant Representations @ https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01991

Could you guys give a detailed explanation of this approach vs transfer learning and others?
Also, why it's gaining traction amongst the ML research community?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Contrastive learning is very intuitive. If I ask you to find the matching animal in the photo below, you can do so quite easily. You understand the animal on left is a "cat" and you want to find another "cat" image on the right side. So, you can **contrast** between similar and dissimilar things.

[image]

Contrastive learning is an approach to formulate this task of finding similar and dissimilar things for a machine. You can train a machine learning model to classify between similar and dissimilar images. There are various choices to make ranging from:

1. **Encoder Architecture**: To convert the image into representations
2. **Similarity measure between two images**: mean squared error, cosine similarity, content loss
3. **Generating the Training Pairs**: manual annotation, self-supervised methods

This [blog post](https://amitness.com/2020/03/illustrated-simclr/) explains the intuition behind contrastive learning and how it is applied in recent papers like **SimCLR** in more detail.

Comment: How is contrastive learning is different from word2vec negative sampling? It seems like the same idea.

Comment: Conceptually, they are pretty similar. In word2vec, you take words coming in same context as positive pairs and other random words as the negative pair. 

In computer vision, you can take 2 augmentations of the same image as the positive pair and augmentation of some other image as the negative pair. Also, different loss functions are used depending on the paper. The paper SimCLR I mentioned uses the “NT-Xent” (Normalized Temperature-Scaled Cross-Entropy Loss).

Comment: "Similarity measure between two images" how much of this depends on using the measure where the the image's loading on the embedding/representation is used to calculate similarity (rather than the raw pixel distance between the two images)?

Comment: are t-SNE/UMAP distances often used to measure "contrast"?

Answer (score 11):

**Contrastive learning** is a framework that learns similar/dissimilar representations from data that are organized into similar/dissimilar pairs. This can be formulated as a **dictionary look-up** problem.

Both **MoCo** and **SimCLR** use varients of a contrastive loss
function, like InfoNCE from the paper *Representation Learning with
Contrastive Predictive Coding*

\begin{eqnarray*}
 \mathcal{L}_{q,k^+,\{k^-\}}=-log\frac{exp(q\cdot k^+/\tau)}{exp(q\cdot
 k^+/\tau)+\sum\limits_{k^-}exp(q\cdot k^-/\tau)} \end{eqnarray*}

> Here q is a query representation, $k^+$ is a representation of the
> positive (similar) key sample, and ${k^−}$ are representations of the
> negative (dissimilar) key samples. $\tau$ is a temperature
> hyper-parameter. In the instance discrimination pretext task (used by
> MoCo and SimCLR), a query and a key form a positive pair if they are
> data-augmented versions of the same image, and otherwise form a
> negative pair. [image: SimCLR vs MoCo]
>
> The contrastive loss can be minimized by various mechanisms that
> differ in **how the keys are maintained**.
>
> In an **end-to-end** mechanism (Fig. 1a), the negative keys are from
> the same batch and updated end-to-end by back-propagation. **SimCLR**,
> is based on this mechanism and requires a large batch to provide a
> large set of negatives.
>
> In the **MoCo** mechanism i.e. **Momentum Contrast** (Fig. 1b), the
> negative keys are maintained in a queue, and only the queries and
> positive keys are encoded in each training batch.

Quoted from a recent research paper, Improved Baselines with Momentum Contrastive Learning @ https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.04297